# Make next html element lower in z-index than the previous one

Tags: html, css

Normal z-index order makes `p` element here to be higher than `h1` element. In my situation both have some background and `h1` is overlapping `p` a little as a visual effect. Both elements are positioned relatively. So as the overlapping happens, `p` hides some part of `h1` element. Is there an elegant solution to give `p` element lower z-index than `h1` element without having to swap them and making them absolutely positioned?

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>description</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the z-index. It should work fine. [Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/EDDT2/)

Sample CSS:

```
h1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    color: blue;
    z-index: 50;
}
p
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks! What was missing in my style is `position: relative;`.

Comment: @SergeyBasharov you said *"Both elements are positioned relatively."* :)

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to set it actually. =)

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add a relative position and z-index to the H1, and a negative top margin to the paragraph.

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/3828786

Answer (score 1):

You can use z-index on relative positioned items. You just need to define the position attribute. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in head section:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1
    {
        z-index:2;
    }
    p
    {
        z-index:2;
    }
</style>
```